# Eslint - 'match' is missing in props validation (react/prop-types)

Tags: reactjs, properties, eslint

My eslint is failing on the following line.

```
  const id = this.props.match.params.personID;
```

How can I fix this. Setting a rule to ignore would be ok. Finding a fix would be better.

Error

```
 severity: 'Error'
    message: ''match' is missing in props validation (react/prop-types)'
    at: '14,27'
    source: 'eslint'
    code: 'react/prop-types'
```

Comment: See [Typechecking With PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) to get started.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you are checking your prop types you also have to verify the shape of match.

If you are using flow:

```
type Props = {
  match: {
    params: {
      field1: number,
      field2: string,
    }
  }
  ...
}

class Component extends React.Component<Props> {
  ...
}
```

If you aren't and are using [PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)...

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  ...
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  match: PropTypes.shape({
    params: PropTypes.shape({
      field1: PropTypes.number.isRequired
      field2: PropTypes.string
    })
  }),
  ...
}
```

Comment: Do you think this is the correct way to do it? Alternatively I got "react/prop-types": 0 in my eslint to work.

Comment: This actually type checks `match` whereas `"react/prop-types": 0` just disables prop type checking in eslint.

Comment: Does not work anymore with **React-router v4** : even with path-to-regexp the parameter is not converted to an integer. ex: `<Route exact path="/user/:id(\d+)" ... />` your PropTypes validation will return: `Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'id' of type 'string'`. Correct me if I missed something (and I'd like to as having to convert beforehand is just boilerplate)